# Select into by batches in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a multi-million result query in SQL Server whose result I need to drop into new table. Using `INTO dbo.new_table` does the job but when record count goes in millions, it takes hours.

Is there a way of batch/loop data load with `SELECT INTO dbo.new_table`?

```
--15 million records returned
--40 columns
SELECT
 col,
 col,
 col,
 col_n
INTO dbo.new_table
FROM tbl LEFT JOIN tbl_a, LEFT JOIN tbl_b LEFT JOIN tbl_n
ORDER BY 1

--would it be possible to FETCH/LIMIT batch while using INTO?
```

Statistics IO (done for 100 records as 15 million result takes almost 2 hours)

`Total logical reads = 2,641`

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'one'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'two'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'three'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'four'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'five'. Scan count 0, logical reads 415, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'six'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'seven'. Scan count 0, logical reads 415, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'eight'. Scan count 1, logical reads 300, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'nine'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Set statistics Time:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 12 ms, elapsed time = 12 ms.

(100 rows affected)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid join syntax, must be a syntax error surely.

Comment: @Stu - this is only as a example to show what I'm aiming at.

Comment: Though I am sure you have overly simplifed the query, you have made it invalid. Perhaps you should be showing us something more representative so that it doesn't derail said question. How do you, for example, know it's the `INTO` that's slow and not your `JOIN`s or the huge amount of data you're retrieving?

Comment: Check the performance of your query in SSMS by choosing the discard results option and using `set statistics time on`

Comment: Create a new staging table with all the data.  Then split it into different pieces.  That way, you separate the work of calculating the results from the work of splitting the data -- and you are much less likely to introduce some sort of error in the batching (i.e. missing rows).

Comment: multi-million is not really informative. The following took 24 seconds on my laptop to insert 9 million rows `SELECT s1.object_id as c1, s2.object_id as c2 INTO NewTable FROM sys.all_objects s1,sys.all_objects s2` - how many rows? How wide are they? What sort of spec is the server?

Comment: @MartinSmith - 15 million records, 40 columns.

Comment: "40 columns" could still mean anything. If they are all `varchar(max)` and had MB of data this will be a lot different from 40 bit columns. Do you know how many GB of data these 15 million rows will consume? But anyway first of all you should identify what the perf of the `SELECT` on its own is - e.g. by just running it on its own and using the "discard results" option in SSMS as suggested above

Comment: I retrive those and update my post soon.

Comment: run your query with `set statistics io on` and paste its output from the `messages` tab into [statisticsparser](http://statisticsparser.com/). Then let us know the total value for `logical reads`.

Comment: I would strongly suspect, as well as data size, the join conditions and `order by` have a big effect. Please [edit] and add table and index definitions, and share query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: your 100 rows reads 20 meg, extrapolating linearly is almost 200gb, so 2.9tb for 15m rows. I suspect your query performance could be improved, but who knows what its doing . Could be crippling tempdb with spills to disk due to poor cardinality or any number of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the execution plan if there is area to improve like creating indexes.

But if you want to use loop to batch insert you can try below example:

```
    DECLARE @id_control INT
    DECLARE @batchSize INT
    DECLARE @results INT
    
    SET @results = 1
    SET @batchSize = 1000000
    SET @id_control = 0
    
    WHILE (@results > 0)
    BEGIN
       -- put your custom code here
insert INTO dbo.new_table
 SELECT
 col,
 col,
 col,
 col_n

FROM tbl LEFT JOIN tbl_a, LEFT JOIN tbl_b LEFT JOIN tbl_n
idcol <= @id_control + @batchSize
ORDER BY idcol

       
       -- very important to obtain the latest rowcount to avoid infinite loops
       SET @results = @@ROWCOUNT
    
       -- next batch
       SET @id_control = @id_control + @batchSize
    END
```

Instead of `idcol` you need to use the unique column name on which you are ordering the data.